# Proc_open problem. How to publish flare config file

Tags: php, laravel, web, updates, proc-open

I have installed php script made in laravel for my web-site: mirkoviclux.rs and everything worked perfectly and today I got this error.

> The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

I found some workaround on stackoverflow but I need help how to do it.

How do I publish flare config file?

> php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config

I'm new to all of this so I really don't have idea where to put his line of code.

I didn't touck anything on web site and didn't make any updates in few last days and suddenly i tried to visit my website and saw that is not working.

This is the error that I getting.

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a third-party hosting, they may have performed maintenance on the same one that generated the problem.
Try to open a ticket in the support of the hosting that they solve themselves. You usually don't have access to this.

If server is managed by you, run the mentioned `php artisan` line via terminal in your project root director and edit the config/flare.php: `'collect_git_information' => false`